# How can show the output like this in Java (condition: elements which can enter is up to 10) (image)

Tags: java, output

[image]

I can use **inputmany()** to enter but when I enter 0 for ***atomicNum*** to want the program stop and run **outputmany()**. But it doesn't.

Here is my code.It is wrong somewhere but I don't know.

---

```java
package workshop3thu;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Workshop3thu {

    public static void inputmany(Workshop3thu[] a, int n) {//n<= 10
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int xatomicNum;
        String xsymbol;
        String xfullname;
        float xweight;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10) {
            System.out.print("Enter atomic number : ");
            xatomicNum = sc.nextInt();
            if (xatomicNum == 0) break;
            else {
                System.out.print("Enter symbol : ");
                xsymbol = sc.next();
                System.out.print("Enter fullname : ");
                xfullname = sc.next();
                System.out.print("Enter weight : ");
                xweight = sc.nextFloat();
            }


        }
    }

    public static void outputmany(Workshop3thu[] a, int n) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }            
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Workshop3thu[] arr;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Atomic Information");
        System.out.println("================== ");
        arr = new Workshop3thu[10];
        Workshop3thu ob = new Workshop3thu();
        inputmany(arr, 10);
        outputmany(arr, 10);

    }

}
```

Comment: For clarification, try entering 0 on first prompt - that should work - it may be an error with weight (your image output doesn't print zinc weight).  Also `i` is never incremented - intentional?  Also output strings do not match code - e.g. "weight" vs "atomic weight".

Comment: The default datatype for input consumed by `Scanner` utility is `String`. Therefore, when you do `if (xatomicNum == 0)`, this always returns `false` and `else` part is executed. Use `if (Integer.parseInt(xatomicNum) == 0)`, then it would work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `outputmany` function doesn't work because the parameter `arr` is never set to anything. I think your intention was to declare some of those variables as class properties.